# cycle through multiple list using itertools.cycle()

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of servers. Every server has a list of name on it.
example:

```
server1 = ['a','b','c']
server2 = ['d','e','f']
server3 = ['g','h','i']
```

I want to iterate per server name not per server. For example after picking `'a'` in `server1`, move to `'d'` (not `'b'`) and so on. If I'm going to use `itertools.cycle()`, do I have to create a list of server to cycle through? My expected result is `['a','d','g','b','e','h','c','f','i']`. Can you give me a simple example on how to cycle in multiple list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one works alright:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, islice, izip, cycle
>>> list(islice(cycle(chain.from_iterable(izip(server1, server2, server3))), 0, 18))
['a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i']
```

Note, the `list` and `islice` are just for demonstration purposes to give something to display and prevent infinite output...

Now, it gets more interesting if you have unequal length lists.  Then `izip_longest` will be your friend, but it might be worth a function at this point:

```
import itertools
def cycle_through_servers(*server_lists):
    zipped = itertools.izip_longest(*server_lists, fillvalue=None)
    chained = itertools.chain.from_iterable(zipped)
    return itertools.cycle(s for s in chained if s is not None)
```

demo:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> server3 = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
>>> list(islice(cycle_through_servers(server1, server2, server3), 0, 20))
['a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i', 'j', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i', 'j']
```

Comment: If you have unquel lenght lists, take a look at [@Anonymous's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29226491/4687645). It is considerably faster if the difference in the list lengths is large

Answer (score 12):

We can also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) which is faster in comparison.

```
import itertools

server1 = ['a','b','c']
server2 = ['d','e','f']
server3 = ['g','h','i']

print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(server1,server2,server3)))
```

Results:

```
['a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i']
```

Comment: It's better to use itertools.izip(), especially in case the input data is large, because zip() returns a list, not iterator, according to docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 9):

You can do it the with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) built-in functions (and in python3 `functools.reduce`):

```
>>> list_of_servers=[server1,server2,server3]
>>> s=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,zip(*list_of_servers))
>>> s
('a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i')
```

Or instead of `reduce()` for long lists you can use `itertools.chain` to concatenate the sub-lists that return a generator:

```
>>> list(chain(*zip(*[server1,server2,server3])))
['a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i']
```

*NOTE* that if you want to iterate over your result you don't have to use `list` on the result of `chain`. You can just do something like:

```
for element in chain(*zip(*[server1,server2,server3])):
     #do stuff
```

Benchmarking on the preceding recipes:

```
#reduce()
:~$ python -m timeit "server1 = ['a','b','c'];server2 = ['d','e','f'];server3 = ['g','h','i'];reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,zip(*[server1,server2,server3]))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 usec per loop
#itertools.chain()
:~$ python -m timeit "server1 = ['a','b','c'];server2 = ['d','e','f'];server3 = ['g','h','i'];from itertools import chain;chain(*zip(*[server1,server2,server3]))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.02 usec per loop
```

Note that if you don't put the servers within a list it would be faster :

```
:~$ python -m timeit "server1 = ['a','b','c'];server2 = ['d','e','f'];server3 = ['g','h','i'];reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,zip(server1,server2,server3))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.98 usec per loop
```

Comment: Note: `compiler.ast.flatten` is deprecated and using `itertools.chain` is very likely to be the most time-efficient solution.

Comment: @Shashank Yes Sure , but chain is good for long lists and for short list like this `reduce` in better! check out the benchmarking!

Comment: @Shashank and thanks for noted that its faster without list! as a container ;)

Comment: I like downvoter care about comment and tell us about his reason!

Comment: Another note: In Python 3, `reduce` has been moved to the `functools` module.

Comment: I found an even faster way using built-in `sum`: `$ python -m timeit "server1 = ['a','b','c'];server2 = ['d','e','f'];server3 = ['g','h','i'];sum(zip(*[server1,server2,server3]),())"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 usec per loop`
`python -m timeit "server1 = ['a','b','c'];server2 = ['d','e','f'];server3 = ['g','h','i'];reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,zip(*[server1,server2,server3]))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 usec per loop` Sorry I keep bugging you, Kasra. :)

Comment: Why the unpacking for `zip`? `zip(*[a,b,c])` is just a complicated way of writing `zip(a, b, c)`. Unpacking is needed only if you don't know the number of elements in the sequence.

Comment: @Bakuriu its because of when the servers are in a list! also i have add an explain about passing the servers without the list at the end part of answer!

Comment: @Kasra, reduce only looks faster because you are including the time it takes to import chain in your calculation. Using `python -mtimeit -s "from itertools import chain"  "server1 = ['a','b','c']; server2 = ['d','e','f']; server3 = ['g','h','i']; chain(*zip(server1, server2, server3));"` to move the import out of the timed block gives me 0.889 usec for chain while your reduce version takes 1.24 usec on my machine

Answer (score 5):

The [standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) provides this function as a recipe in `itertools`.

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

This code works even when the iterables are of uneven lengths, cycling through remaining ones when the shorter ones are used up. That may or may not be relevant to your use-case.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
from itertools import cycle
for k in cycle([j for i in zip(server1,server2,server3) for j in i]):
   print(k)
   #do you operations

a
d
g
b
...
```

But **care** this provides infinite loop

So better do this:

```
c = cycle([j for i in zip(server1,server2,server3) for j in i])

>>>next(c)
a
>>>next(c)
b
....
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import chain
for s in chain(*zip(server1, server2, server3)):
    # do work
```

Comment: I did it as `chain(* map(lambda *args: args, *(server1, server2, server3))`  but I will prefer yours and @Anonymous answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use chain:

```
import itertools

server1 = ['a','b','c']
server2 = ['d','e','f']
server3 = ['g','h','i']


all_servers = [server1, server2, server3] 

out_list = [s_name for a in itertools.chain(zip(*all_servers)) for s_name in a]

print(out_list)
#['a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i']
```

Or shorter:

```
out_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*all_servers)))
```

Comment: Isn't `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*all_servers)))` cleaner than the nested list-comp?

Comment: @mgilson Yes, but such answer already exists, so I did not want to duplicate it. Its alternative. But I added it now also.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) you can simply do this:

```
from itertools import chain, izip
server1 = [1, 2]
server2 = [3, 4]
server3 = [4, 5]
print list(chain(*izip(server1, server2, server3))) # [1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5]
```

Or you can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), it expects an iterable that itself generates iterators.

In your case [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is that iterable, it generates iterators in the form of tuples:

```
print list(chain.from_iterable(zip(server1, server2, server3))) # [1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5]
```

[`yield`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) too could be used here:

```
def f():
    server1 = [1, 2]
    server2 = [3, 4]
    server3 = [4, 5]
    for a, b, c in zip(server1, server2, server3):
        yield a
        yield b
        yield c

val = f()
print [val.next() for _ in range(6)] # [1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5]
```