# check identical for list in list(python)

Tags: python, list

I want to check if there is no identical entries in a list of list. If there are no identical matches, then return True, otherwise False.

For example:

```
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]  # False
[[1,2,3],[10,20,30]] # True
```

I am thinking of combine all of the entries into one list,
for example: change [[1,2,3][4,5,6]] into [1,2,3,4,5,6] and then check

Thanks for editing the question and helping me!

Comment: I don't understand what is causing your second example to return True

Comment: @BillLynch because there is no identical number, 1,2,3,10,20,30 are different

Comment: So should `[[1,3], [1,2]]` return true?

Comment: Should `[[1,1]]` return true?

Comment: @wim i may confuse u. if there is no identical, then true. if there has identical numbers, return false

Comment: @user4710021: I gave 2 examples. Are they both false?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using this method will make the boolean variable "same" turn to True if there is a number in your list that occurs more than once as the .count() function returns you how many time a said number was found in the list.

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
same = False
for nbr in li:
    if li.count(nbr) > 1:
        same = True
```

Comment: unnecessarily *O(n^2)*

Comment: Thanks! that is a quick way of making it

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def flat_unique(list_of_lists):
...     flat = [element for sublist in list_of_lists for element in sublist]
...     return len(flat) == len(set(flat))
... 
>>> flat_unique([[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]])
False
>>> flat_unique([[1,2,3],[10,20,30]])
True
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29226470/3270800) and [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) built-in function.

```
import itertools

def check_iden(data):
    return len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))) == len(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data)))

data1 = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]

data2 = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]    

print check_iden(data1)

print check_iden(data2)
```

Returns

```
False
True
```

Comment: You have to be careful with these itertools solutions because it will fail for strings

Comment: thanks for letting me know itertools, i never used that before

Answer (score 0):

You could use sets which have intersection methods to find which elements are common

Answer (score 0):

Place all elements of each sublist into a separate list. If that separate list has any duplicates (call `set()` to find out), then `return False`. Otherwise `return True`.

```
def identical(x):
    newX = []
    for i in x:
        for j in i:
            newX.append(j)
    if len(newX) == len(set(newX)): # if newX has any duplicates, the len(set(newX)) will be less than len(newX)
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can flat the list and count the element in it, then compare it with `set()`

```
import itertools
a = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]] 
b = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]

def check(l):
    merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
    if len(set(merged)) < len(merged):
        return False
    else:
        return True


print check(a)  # False
print check(b)  # True
```

Comment: i never heard of "itertools" before, thanks for letting me know new things

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data you might not want to look at all the elements, here is a solution that returns `False` as soon as you hit a first duplicate.

```
def all_unique(my_lists):
    my_set = set()
    for sub_list in my_lists:
        for ele in sub_list:
            if ele in my_set:
                return False
            my_set.add(ele)
    else:
        return True
```

Result:

```
In [12]: all_unique([[1,2,3],[10,20,30]])
Out[12]: True

In [13]: all_unique([[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]])
Out[13]: False
```